# add initial data to a Django ModelForm using JavaScript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

All,

I am displaying modelformsets in my view.  I am using the JQuery dynamic-formset plugin [http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/] to handle adding/deleting individual forms within that formset.

When I add a new form, I want to give users the option of choosing a model from the database to populate that form with.  I use an AJAX call to a Django view get the available models.  Another AJAX call gets the `form.initial` data of the form corresponding to the selected model.  My question is how to I take that initial data and populate the newly added form with it on the template (in the client - in JavaScript).  Here is some relevant code:

view to get initial data:

```
def get_content(request):
    app_to_get = request.GET.get('a', None)
    model_to_get = request.GET.get('m', None)
    id_to_get = request.GET.get('i',"")
    if not app_to_get and not model_to_get and not id_to_get:
        print "invalid or incomplete app/model/id combination"
        raise Http404()

    id_to_get = int(id_to_get)    

    # these two fns get me the appropriate classes for the model_to_get
    # they work and are irrelevant for my current question    
    model_class = get_model_from_name(model_to_get,app_to_get)
    form_class = get_form_from_model(model_class)

    model = model_class.objects.get(pk=id_to_get)
    form = form_class(instance=model)    

    formTemplate = Template("{{ form.initial }}")
    formContext  = Context({"form" : form})

    return HttpResponse(formTemplate.render(formContext));
```

And here is some JavaScript:

```
function add_model() {
        var url = window.document.location.protocol + "//" + window.document.location.host + "/get_content/";
        url += "?a=" + app_to_add_to + "&m=" + model_to_add + "&i=" + id_to_add;

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : 'get',
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
                /* I AM HERE I AM HERE I AM HERE */
            }
        });
        return true;
    };
```

At this point, `data` looks something like this:

```
{'url': u'http://www.foo.com/', 'id': 2, 'title': u'foo'}
```

But I don't know how to map that data to my newly-added form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set the value of the relevant fields with the associated data:

```
$('#some_field').val(data.some_value);
```

You'll have to figure out what id your fields are given, since it will most likely be some form of `#field_id_[N]` where N is the iteration of the added form. Just introspect the document source in something like Firebug to see what the HTML looks like for generated forms.

**General Notes**

1. Don't use `print` in view code. In development `print` will output to the console because the Django development server runs interactively, but in production that will end up in some log file or nowhere at all. Always raise an exception if something is not right and you want to be notified of it or deliberately log it with the actual Django logging utilities.
2. Raising Http404 when data isn't provided is not really the best way to handle the situation, especially when dealing with AJAX. Returning `HttpResponseBadRequest()` would probably be more appropriate, reserving the `Http404` exception for when the provided data literally doesn't match anything in the database.
3. It's unnecessary to convert `id_to_get` to an `int` if you're merely passing it into a query. It won't hurt anything, but it's just extraneous code.
4. If you're dealing with generic content types like this, you should use the facilities present in the `contenttypes` framework, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will give it a try.  And I will make the changes you suggested in your notes 1-3.  I'll look into note 4.

Comment: +1, All good points (although print statements in views are a guilty pleasure for me). Number 5: Return json data instead of the string representation of the initial dictionary. It will make the javascript much easier.

Comment: @Alasdair: something about the response bugged me, but I completely spaced-out on the fact that this is supposed to be an AJAX response. Haha, good catch.

Comment: @Chris:  I still haven't gotten this working, but that's only because your other suggestions have prompted me to rewrite loads of my code.  It is now much more efficient.  Thanks.